# List of filenames Sorting in Jenkins piepline based on file extension

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a list which contains file names(change log) in Jenkins pipeline. I am looking to sort that list based on file extension.

example - **lines = [a.yaml, b.sql, c.json, d.py, e.txt]**

I would like to sort this list as below-
**lines = [c.json, d.py, b.sql, e.txt, a.yaml]**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Groovy Sort](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#_sorting) with a custom comparator. Please refer to the following sample.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def lines = ["a.yaml", "b.sql", "c.json", "d.py", "e.txt"]
                    echo "Not sorted: $lines"               
                    sortFiles(lines)
                    echo "Sorted: $lines"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@NonCPS
def sortFiles(def files) {
    return files.sort { s1, s2 -> s1.substring(s1.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) <=> s2.substring(s2.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) }
}
```

#### Update

Bringing files without a extension to the top

```
@NonCPS
def sortFiles(def files) {
return files.sort { s1, s2 -> 
        def s1Index = s1.lastIndexOf('.')
        def s2Index = s2.lastIndexOf('.')
        if((s1Index == -1)) { // S1 doesn't have an extension, S1 comes first 
            return -1
        } else if (s2Index == -1) { // S1 have an extension but S2 doesn't so s2 comes first
            return 1
        } else {
            return s1.substring(s1Index + 1) <=> s2.substring(s2Index + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, But when I incorporated and test it there is one edge case came up, where I can get file without extension (Jenkin in which I am making this change). How can I ignore that file passing to this function but still can keep as first element in the list?

Comment: @Vishal please find the updated answer.